# JQuery UI add id to dialog

Tags: css, jquery-ui

How can I add id to specific dialog?
I just want to apply separate style for each dialog and try doing it like this:

```
var $order_dialog = $("<%= escape_javascript(render('order_mini_site_form', :layout => false)) %>");

var current_dialog = $order_dialog.dialog({
  width: 515,
  height: 575,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  title: false,
  autoOpen: true,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  buttons: [
    { text: "Отправить запрос" , click: function() { $(this).find('form').submit();    $(this).dialog('close'); } },
    { text: "Отмена", click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
  ]
}).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();


$current_dialog.attr('id', 'awesome_dialog');
```

but dialog created inside body tag without id and I cant apply style for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your goal is just to use this id in the css, you can achieve this with a css class instead.

The [dialogClass](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-dialogClass) option allows you to specify a class that will be applied to the dialog. You can then use this class in your selectors to apply a different style for a specific dialog.

Comment: I try class and it's working for me. Thanks. But ID is better in my opinion - it has higher priority than class selector.. thats why I'm looking for ability to add ID.

Comment: Yeah, but since the API doesn't provide anything for the ID, you have to use a class, or to hack. If you absolutely want an ID, you can use the following hack (but it's a bit dirty). Just after opening your popup, you can remove the class and add the id. $(".your-class").removeClass(".your-class").attr("id", "your-id"). However, I think that the "dirtyness" cause by using a class where you want an ID hurts less than this horrible hack. And you can always increase the priority of your rule with repeating the whole rule with your class

Answer (score 11):

A bit late, but this is how it could be done:

```
$('#placeholderId').dialog('widget').attr('id', 'dialogId');
```

***$('#placeholderId').dialog('widget')*** gives you the surrounding <div> of the dialog, which is most likely the element you want to set the ID on.

Comment: I find it INSANE that jquery dialog does not have options for adding a class/id to the parent. I mean, completely insane. Also insane is the fact dialog boxes have no container (except the outer container) for the title and content div ...

Comment: Best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your example code is that you are adding the `id` to the result of `.find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove()` instead of the dialog itself.  The following should work for you.

```
var $order_dialog = $("<%= escape_javascript(render('order_mini_site_form', :layout => false)) %>");

var current_dialog = $order_dialog.dialog({
  width: 515,
  height: 575,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
  id: "ololo",
  title: false,
  autoOpen: true,
  closeOnEscape: false,
  buttons: [
    { text: "Отправить запрос" , click: function() { $(this).find('form').submit();                $(this).dialog('close'); } },
    { text: "Отмена", click: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); } }
  ]
})

$current_dialog.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
$current_dialog.attr('id', 'awesome_dialog');
```

Comment: There are plenty of options.  I personally would include the `id` in the HTML itself, in your case on the `order_mini_site_form`.  You could also use a CSS class per the `dialogClass` option as another answerer mentioned.  As a last option if you only have one dialog on the page you could just use the `ui-dialog` class jQuery UI already puts on the dialog.  For example `ui-dialog { color: yellow; }` will make all text on the dialog yellow.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the voted answer (not a personal attack just disagree with the "dirty hack" part). He is true that there is no ID option for jquery Dialog Box, however should you come to the conclusion that an ID is necessary, the following code should suffice. My tour guide JS I'm developing was very much in need of such an ID.

// Here I'm declaring the dynamically inserted content [e.g what I'm creating] to have an ID of tempstep, this will be used with the call below to add an ID to the jQuery Dialog Box

Code : `jQuery ('<div id="tempstep"></div>').dialog({`

Code : `jQuery('#tempstep').parent().attr("id","dialogBox");`